# Can all elements of all rings be multiplied by positive integers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let's say we have an arbitrary ring $R$ and an element $a \in R$, and we have a positive integer $n \in ℤ^{+}$. What can we say about the multiplication operations $an$ and $na$? Do they exist in ring $R$? What is the proof? Are there any other properties of this operation? Since multiplication within a ring is associative, is multiplication of an arbitrary ring with members of $ℤ^{+}$ also associative? What about distributivity? Or commutativity if $R$ has commutative multiplication?

Context: I'm being asked to prove $m(na) = (mn)a$ where $a \in R$ and $m, n \in ℤ^{+}$, and I assume that both sides are $\in R$, but I don't know what the proof is for the first step of $na$ (and for the subsequent steps). I don't know what the rules are for operations that have one member inside a ring and one member outside of the ring.

Comment: Define the operation inductively by $1\cdot a=a, (n+1)a=na+a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how one can define a $\mathbb{Z}$-action on any ring $R$ (note that I included the negative integers) :
$$
\begin{aligned}
0\cdot a &= 0\\
n\cdot a &= \underbrace{a+\ldots+a}_n\quad n>0\\
n\cdot a &= \underbrace{(-a)+\ldots+(-a)}_{-n}\quad n<0
\end{aligned}$$
Note @saulspatz's alternative inductive definition in the comments. Then all your questions basically follow from the same arguments one could do about the multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}$ :

- it is associative because *addition* in the ring is associative
- it is distributive because *addition* in the ring is commutative
- it is commutative (follow from the definition)

Note that these properties never use the multiplicative structure of the ring: the only thing needed is the abelian group structure. Actually, the above is exactly saying that an abelian group is the same as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Comment: Re: your last sentence, it's also the case that every *ring* is a $\mathbb{Z}$-*algebra*. This brings back the multiplicative structure.

Comment: @NoahSchweber ℤ-algebra, or ℤ-multiplyable? I don't think you can add a member of ℤ to a matrix, for example.

Comment: @AaronFranke No, [I meant what I said](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field#Generalization:_algebra_over_a_ring).